# Is there a way to have a top-bar with a header image that are sticky together at the top of the page?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm building a website for a friend's film production company using Foundation 6. I created a top-bar navigation bar with his logo image above the top-bar and made them both sticky. It seems to work fine on large screens and small screens but if viewed on anything in between the logo separates from the top-bar. This is most evident when you stretch and squish the page.

I've tried to include the image in the top-bar div but it aligns it to the left and I haven't been able to align it to the top as it is currently. This is the first time I've worked with the sticky function in Foundation. I've looked through the Foundation docs, Google, and StackOverflow but haven't found anything quite like this.

This is my top-bar section.

```
<div data-sticky-container>
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="example-menu"></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

    <div class="grid-y">
              <img src="images/safe_image.jpeg" style="width: 100%; height: auto"; data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;">
<div class="top-bar"  data-sticky data-options="marginTop:10.2;" style="width:100%; background-color: white; padding-top: 10px;" id="example-menu">
<!--    <div class="top-bar" style="width:100%; background-color: white; padding-top: 10px;" id="example-menu"> -->
  <div class="top-bar-right" data-dropdown-menu style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" style="background-color: white;">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.html">Current News</a></li>
      <li><a href="film.html">Film/Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="publicity.html">Publicity</a></li>
      <li><a href="miscellaneous.html">Misc</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

I would like the logo image and the navigation bar to look the way they do at larger screen sizes but minimize together to the point where the data-toggle kicks in instead of separating, as they are doing currently.